# 2014 community ads still being used

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Richard Dawkins is appearing in the community ads.

[image: Dick's photo]

Currently he's got 6 votes in the 2014 community ads, but isn't listed in the 2015 community promotion ads.

Why are we still using the 2014 community ads in the sidebar? Is this a bug?

Comment: I can't answer officially, but I think it is related to the fact the [replacement ad announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246237/no-sign-of-community-promotion-ads-2015) went out later than normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From Anna Lear on Meta Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246453/old-community-promotion-ads-still-showing-up):

> Thanks for catching this, but for the moment this is working as
>   intended. The ads are still running off of the old 2014 meta posts for
>   two reasons:
>
> 1. The new posts only went up a couple days ago and we normally wait a bit to have them pick up speed.
> 2. Holidays/vacations happened.
>
> We should be switching over to the new ads sometime next week.